# Adding views with subviews programmatically, in loop

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, copy

Referencing this question here on copying views with subviews [Copy of UiView and all subviews..Copied UIButton cannot be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917743/copy-of-uiview-and-all-subviews-copied-uibutton-cannot-be-pressed/53918604#53918604)

In the link above, copying a view and all its subviews is possible, however, I have been unsuccessful in creating a loop that will create as many or as little views.

My attempt has been adding views into a stack view that is inside a scroll view so that you are able to scroll down if many views are required:

```
var numOfViewsNeeded = 5

func createPart() -> UIView {
    let part = UIView()
    part.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    part.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    part.layer.masksToBounds = true
    part.backgroundColor = .random()
    part.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

    let partLabel1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))
    let partLabel2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 35, width: 300, height: 50))
    let partLabel3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 75, width: 300, height: 50))
    let partLabel4 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 115, width: 300, height: 50))
    let partLabel5 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 155, width: 300, height: 50))
    let partLabel6 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 195, width: 300, height: 50))
    partLabel1.text = "NO."
    partLabel1.textColor = .white
    partLabel2.text = "Code"
    partLabel2.textColor = .white
    partLabel3.text = "Br"
    partLabel3.textColor = .white
    partLabel4.text = "Stat"
    partLabel4.textColor = .white
    partLabel5.text = "Line"
    partLabel5.textColor = .white
    partLabel6.text = "B"
    partLabel6.textColor = .white

    part.addSubview(partLabel1)
    part.addSubview(partLabel2)
    part.addSubview(partLabel3)
    part.addSubview(partLabel4)
    part.addSubview(partLabel5)
    part.addSubview(partLabel6)

    part.layer.zPosition = -1]
    return part
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let part = createPart()
     for i in 0..<numOfViewsNeeded {
         view.addSubview(part)
         stackView.addArrangedSubview(part)
      }
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.containerScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    containerScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    containerScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


containerScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    containerScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    stackMainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    stackMainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    stackMainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    //stackMainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(self.heighOfStack)).isActive = true
    stackMainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    }

var containerScrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    return scrollView
}()

var contentView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return view
}()
let stackMainView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.backgroundColor = .random()
    return stackView

}()
```

Is this process of 'dynamically' creating the same view over and over possible ?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m not sure, but wouldn’t be better to use `UITableView` instead of `UIStackView` in your case?

Comment: i like the stack views, of course the table View is also viable. Is this not possible using stack views and the method I have used? Is a table view the only possible way?

Comment: no, you can do it with stack view, but you would have to do lot of things which you *get for free* with Table View

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can do this with a scroll view and stack view.

Your main problem was that you are creating your "part" *outside* of the for loop:

```
    // this creates ONE part view
    let part = createPart()
    // your loop simply adds and re-adds that one part view
    for i in 0..<numOfViewsNeeded {
        view.addSubview(part)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(part)
    }
```

It should look like this:

```
    for i in 0..<numOfViewsNeeded {
        // create a new part view
        let part = createPart()
        // add that new view to the stack view
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(part)
    }
```

Here is a modified version of your code that would give you the result you want:

```
class AddStuffViewController: UIViewController {

    var numOfViewsNeeded = 5

    var bkgColors: [UIColor] = [
        .blue,
        .green,
        .red,
        .orange,
        .yellow
    ]

    func createPart(_ n: Int) -> UIView {
        let part = UIView()
        part.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        part.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        part.layer.masksToBounds = true
        part.backgroundColor = bkgColors[n] // .random()
        part.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

        let partLabel1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))
        let partLabel2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 35, width: 300, height: 50))
        let partLabel3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 75, width: 300, height: 50))
        let partLabel4 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 115, width: 300, height: 50))
        let partLabel5 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 155, width: 300, height: 50))
        let partLabel6 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 195, width: 300, height: 50))
        partLabel1.text = "NO."
        partLabel1.textColor = .white
        partLabel2.text = "Code"
        partLabel2.textColor = .white
        partLabel3.text = "Br"
        partLabel3.textColor = .white
        partLabel4.text = "Stat"
        partLabel4.textColor = .white
        partLabel5.text = "Line"
        partLabel5.textColor = .white
        partLabel6.text = "B"
        partLabel6.textColor = .white

        part.addSubview(partLabel1)
        part.addSubview(partLabel2)
        part.addSubview(partLabel3)
        part.addSubview(partLabel4)
        part.addSubview(partLabel5)
        part.addSubview(partLabel6)

        return part
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(containerScrollView)
        containerScrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(stackMainView)

        for i in 0..<numOfViewsNeeded {
            let part = createPart(i)
            stackMainView.addArrangedSubview(part)
        }

        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.containerScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.containerScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.containerScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        containerScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        containerScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        stackMainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        stackMainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        stackMainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        stackMainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(stackMainView.arrangedSubviews.count)
    }

    var containerScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .gray
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        return scrollView
    }()

    var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        view.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return view
    }()
    let stackMainView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        return stackView

    }()
}
```

Note: if you think you may be needing *lots* of parts, you a probably better off using a table view and designing the "part" as a reusable cell.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can loop through and create multiple items.

```
let yArray = [0, 35, 75, 115, 155, 195]
let textArray ["NO.", "Code", "Br", "Stat", "Line", "B"]

var numOfViewsNeeded = 5

func createPart() -> UIView {
    let part = UIView()
    part.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    part.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    part.layer.masksToBounds = true
    part.backgroundColor = .random()
    part.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

    for index in 0...numOfViewNeeded-1 {
        let partLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: yArray[index], width: 300, height: 50))
        partLabel.text = "\(textArray[index])"
        partLabel.textColor = .white
        part.addSubview(partLabel)
    }

    part.layer.zPosition = -1
    return part
}
```

This is without using tableView's or stackView. Does this work for you?

Comment: sorry this does not seem to work on its own.. does not create multiple views